# Android - Layout not in uniform

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have a horizontal list of images in my android application. But the problem is some of the images seems to not follow the layout I've defined in my xml. Like this:

[image: suppose to be it should be in uniform distance]

my layouts look like this:
**mainlayout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back_shop_list"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

  <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
      android:id="@+id/shop_hlist_view" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingLeft="5dp"
      android:paddingRight="5dp"
      android:scrollX="1dp"
      android:scrollY="1dp"
      android:overScrollMode="always" >  
  </com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

then my **listlayout.xml**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:translationY="200dp" >  

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/framelayout" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"    
            android:clickable="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="360dp" />  

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/img_progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:translationY="150dp"
            android:translationX="140dp" /> 

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:translationX="10dp"
        android:textColor="#dc6800"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <!-- Description label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:translationX="10dp"
        android:textColor="#acacac"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My guess is that the size of my image is lesser than what my ImageView layout_width and height. Or I dont really know what causes this problem.
But any help will do, please. Thanks.

EDIT: What I really wanted is that if the image is like image 4 and image 5, it should not have those spaces. I've tried getting the size of the image from my ImageLoader then set the layout parameters height and width in there while images are loaded. But it looked worse. 
Are there other ways in which i can dynamically adjust my ImageView if ever the images are like image 4 and 5?

Comment: Add android:scaleType to your ImageView.  Try the different options - probably FIT_CENTER will do what you want.

Comment: I guess you want to add a image, and it wil be resized to the width and height of screen ?

Comment: yes, i add image and resize it to the width and height of the view..not the screen

Comment: @Simon okay, i will try those things.

Comment: my images looked bad. can i just get the size of my image and then adjust my imageView in the activity?

Comment: set mach_parent as the height of the images.. so all the images will be look like same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If actually you want to make the image occupy the desired space

try adding  this image View property to your ImageView

You can try others I usually  use `fitXY` out of the predefined list you will get there in XML Layout

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

so as to make this property work we also need

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

that you have already added in your case

### If actually you want to avoid on blank spaces and let the image occupy as much space as it want

In my layout I am using two image views to show a demo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_numbers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_numbers"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_numbers"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:src="@drawable/desert"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:background="@drawable/desert"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

ImageView 1 is assigning image as *Source* using `android:src="@drawable/desert"`

and below is the result as you can notice that it is showing **WhiteSpace** arround it.

[image]

ImageView2 is  assigning image as *Background* using `android:background="@drawable/desert"`
and below is the result as you can notice that it is showing no **WhiteSpace** arround it.

[image]

Or try using these attributes to make it possible

```
android:maxHeight=""
        android:maxWidth=""
        android:minHeight=""
        android:minWidth=""
```

Comment: my images looked bad. what i mean with the question is that if the image is smaller, it should not have those extra spaces.

Comment: so, there's no way that i could just adjust my layout width and height according to the size of the image loaded from url?

Comment: try following my above update if any of these attribute didn't helped you..atleast i don't know if there is any other way to fix it..

as we are giving the fixed layout-width and fixed layout-height in XML layout its behaving actually the way it should..

Comment: set your imageview's width to "wrap_content".

Comment: it gives white space when it try to maintain the accept ratio of image in your provided dimensions of image-view.. so you cant say it with surety that image with small size is doing this... its actually the accept ratio of the image....

if you want to make the image occupy the size of the actual image use "wrap-content"(which actually I don't think so you want to do, as large image coming thru URL will spoil you whole layout)... or let it to fill the space using "scale-type" (I would have atleast opted for the later)

Comment: sad to say, i didn't help my problem, what i did is that i just 
i gave my layout width and height values.
I tried the other attributes, but still there are extra spaces.
Also, one of my solution was resize the uploaded images of the user in the server side. 
But, the first answer works for those who really want to scale, so i'll just give this answer a check.